# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} to specific URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I migrating an old site over to WordPress and am currently setting up various 301 Redirects for the .aspx pages. The old site used query strings to display certain pages so I am wanting to map these to the new SEO URLS.

My current code for the basic 'static' pages works fine:

```
Redirect 301 /about-us.aspx http:// example.com/about-us/
Redirect 301 /get-in-touch.aspx http:// example.com/contact/
Redirect 301 /services.aspx http:// example.com/services/
```

The problem lies with the following query strings:

```
Redirect 301 /services.aspx?type=14 http:// example.com/services/service-a/
Redirect 301 /services.aspx?type=17 http:// example.com/services/service-b/
```

I have since read that I must use RewriteCond in order to properly redirect these query strings. I read on simonecarletti's blog the following would work passing the query string onto the end of the URI.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.site/page/%1.pdf [R=302,L]
```

This is not practical for me as I have keywords in their URLs named after the services. The id numbers mean nothing.

After reading a few questions here [11544773, 25621398, 17919953] I've been experimenting with various suggestions without any luck.

All that happens is if I visit:

```
/services.aspx?type=14
```

I am redirected to:

```
/services/?type=14
```

**How can I redirect to the new URI, e.g.**

```
/services/service-a/
```

Here is the mess of code I am playing about with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=14$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/services\.aspx$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/service-a/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have should work, you just need to check for the services in the URI:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=14$
RewriteRule ^services\.aspx$ http://example.com/services/service-a/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tired your amendment and at first nothing happened. Then it dawned on me. These rules all needed to be called before the WordPress RewriteRules. Working as expected